# Get video from kinect to an object in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, kinect, kinect-sdk

how can I get the video live feed from kinect V1 and use it over a plane or over an UI object? is it possible? or perhaps if I wan't to take/save a photograph with kinect's camera.

I'm using the kinect with ms sdk asset
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/kinect-with-ms-sdk-7747

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this from the asset developer 
You can get the color camera texture from the KinectManager-component in your script, like this: Texture clrTex = KinectManager.Instance.GetUsersClrTex(); Then just assign this texture to the renderer's material texture (in case of 3d object) or to the raw image's texture (in case of UI). This will display the color camera output on the object at runtime.